# Factor out the following expression $ -5 a^3 b^3 c + 125abc $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I was doing some factoring exercises and encountered the following problem. The idea is to simplify the expression.

$$ -5  a^3  b^3  c + 125abc $$

1. We find the GCD and bring it outside $$ 5abc(-a^2b^2+25) $$
2. Now we apply Binomial Decomposition $$ -a^2b^2+25 = (5+ab)(5-ab) $$

And here is the part I don't get. Could you please explain why it became $ (5+ab)(5-ab) $ in the expression? And not $ (-ab+5)(ab+5) $

What is the rule that allows us to swap expression/change the sign?

I hope you understand what I don't understand ?

Thank you

Comment: Addition and multiplication are **both** commutative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: $(-ab+5)(ab+5)=(ab+5)(-ab+5)$

Step 2: $(-ab+5)=(5-ab)$, so $(ab+5)(-ab+5)=(ab+5)(5-ab)$

Step 3: $(ab+5)=(5+ab)$, so $(ab+5)(5-ab)=(5+ab)(5-ab)$

Comment: Could you give more explanation why (-ab+5) = (5 - ab)? Thanks

Comment: Because addition is abelian.  $x+y=y+x$, for any $x,y$.  $((-ab)+5)=(5+(-ab))=(5-ab)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly the same thing because the sum of two numbers commutes ($a-b = -b+a$ is an identity).